# Least Squares with experimental data

Tags: least-squares

HI everyone I have a question on my study guide I dont know how to attack. Here is the question:

[image]

My attempt at making sense of the problem:
The problem provides us with the sum of squares (SS) (I believe that's the 18.1). We can use the SS along with the number of samples(21)to get the standard error. Then somehow use this information to find the probability of having a worse fit?? Upon more research I believe the value given as 18.1 is mean square deviation, or sample variance not the sum of squares. If it is true then an F test certainly makes sense for part b.

Could someone guide me in the right direction and show me how to attempt this question. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems to me that part (a) is asking for a p-value and  part (b), you are testing which of two nested models is the better fit (this is an F-test of some sort)

Comment: @MTurgeon Thanks for the response I will try this!

Comment: This is Statistics question. You would get better results at http://stats.stackexchange.com/